# Как сделать так, чтобы Python не запоминал число

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно, чтобы после вычисления Python не запоминала число.
К примеру вот код:

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
a=a-a+b
b=b-b+a
print(a,b)
```

Он получает на вход числа 5 и 8. Надо, чтобы он вывел ответ 8 и 5. Как сделать так?

Comment: `a, b = (a-a+b, b-b+a)` так пойдёт?

Answer (score 5):

Не очень понятно, в чем вопрос и в чем проблема. Если нужно вывести числа в другом порядке, то нужно выводить их в другом порядке:

```
print (b, a)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())

a, b = b, a

print(a,b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Я не понял как вам нужно, если по средствам математики то

```
a = int( input() )
b = int( nput() )
c = b-a
a = a + c
b = b - c
print( a, b)
```

а если по средствам программирования то

```
a = int( input() )
b=int( input() )
print( b, a)
```